# SWIFT append data to dictionary

Tags: swift, dictionary, append

I'm having trouble coding an apparently simple task.  I want to add new client profile data to a client profile dictionary (clientDatabase) but keep getting errors - can't seem to append - error: value of type '(String: clientProfile)' has no member 'append'  (see error at bottom of code)

Any insights you can provide are greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Bill

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import UIKit
import Foundation



/*
code copied from B-C Dev Database - structs but simplified with fewer variables 
goal is to getappend new client to work.
*/

/*
Globals: these go in main.swift file
*/

struct clientProfile {

    var firstName: String = ""
    var lastName: String = ""
    var group: Int = 0
}
//var clientDatabase : NSMutableDictionary! = [String:clientProfile]()
var clientDatabase:[String:clientProfile]

/* sample data template: phone is key, sub array is;
(firstName: "", lastName: "",pilatesGroup:  )
*/
clientDatabase = [
    "1234567": clientProfile(firstName: "Sally", lastName: "Sillious", group: 3),
    "2345678": clientProfile(firstName: "Sue", lastName: "Parker",group: 8),
    "3456789": clientProfile(firstName: "Bob", lastName: "Parker",  group: 2),
    "5678901": clientProfile(firstName: "Jim", lastName: "Beam", group: 12)
        ]

clientDatabase.count

// so far so good

/*
add new client
declare local variables in scene swift files where used
*/
var firstName: String = ""
var phone:String = ""
var newPhone: String = ""
var newFirstName: String = ""
var newLastName: String = ""
var newGroup: Int = 0
// define struct using these input variables for values but with same keys as (global) clientDatabase

struct newClientProfile {

    var firstName: String = newFirstName
    var lastName: String = newLastName
    var group: Int = newGroup
}

// put newClientProfile into newClientDictionary
var newClientDatabase:Dictionary = [String:newClientProfile]()

// input values from scene - UITextFields
newPhone = "4567890"
newFirstName = "Super"
newLastName = "Dave"
newGroup = 14

// test that all values are where they should be
clientDatabase
clientDatabase.count
newClientDatabase = [newPhone:newClientProfile()]
newClientDatabase.count
// ok so far

//the following line returns an error
clientDatabase.append(newClientDatabase)    
// can't seem to append - error value of type '(String: clientProfile)' has no member 'append'
```

Answer (score 2):

Two things. First of all `clientDatabase` is a dictionary which doesn't have `append`, instead you'll have to iterate through the other dictionary and insert its elements into `clientDatabase`.

The other issue is that `clientDatabase` and `newClientDatabase` aren't the same type. The first one is `[String : clientProfile]` and the second is `[String : newClientProfile]`. You'll have to convert the values from one type to the other to combine the dictionaries.

Looking deeper into the code there some misunderstandings about the language. For example:

```
struct newClientProfile {

  var firstName: String = newFirstName
  var lastName: String = newLastName
  var group: Int = newGroup
}

// put newClientProfile into newClientDictionary
var newClientDatabase:Dictionary = [String:newClientProfile]()
```

You're creating a struct just for the purpose of containing a single set of values when you already have `clientProfile`. Instead you could do:

```
var newClientProfile = clientProfile(firstName: newFirstName, lastName: newLastName, group: newGroup)
```

This will create a variable which is an instance of `clientProfile` and stores the information you want. However, you have the other variables defined as empty values.

Here's a cleaned up version of your code, take a look at it and let me know if you have any questions.

```
struct ClientProfile { // Convention is to use initial caps for enum, struct, class
  let firstName: String
  let lastName: String
  let group: Int
}

var clientDatabase = [
  "1234567": ClientProfile(firstName: "Sally", lastName: "Sillious", group: 3),
  "2345678": ClientProfile(firstName: "Sue", lastName: "Parker",group: 8),
  "3456789": ClientProfile(firstName: "Bob", lastName: "Parker",  group: 2),
  "5678901": ClientProfile(firstName: "Jim", lastName: "Beam", group: 12)
]

// input values from scene - UITextFields
let newPhone = "4567890"
let newFirstName = "Super"
let newLastName = "Dave"
let newGroup = 14

// define struct using these input variables for values but with same keys as (global) clientDatabase
let newClientProfile = ClientProfile(firstName: newFirstName, lastName: newLastName, group: newGroup)
let newClientDatabase = [newPhone:newClientProfile]

for (phone,client) in newClientDatabase {
  clientDatabase[phone] = client
}
```

Comment: Thanks Kenneth, for your quick response.  I tried out the code and it does what I need.  And thanks for your other insights.